# What is the most efficient way to execute code if a while loop runs at least once?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop, and I want some line of code to be run if the while loop runs at least once. If the while loop does not run, I want to skip this line of code.

```
while(condition) {
  doSomething();
}
doSomethingElse(); 
/* Only run doSomethingElse() if the while loop ran
at least once */
```

I could set a bool to false before it runs, and set it to true when it runs, but to me it feels a little messy. Also, this while loop is inside a function that can run up to 10^6 times, and it has time constraints, so I want it to run as efficiently as possible. Is there any way to do this?

*note: Do not confuse this with a do-while loop which runs at least once no matter what. I want a line of code that runs only if the while loop is run at least once.

Comment: Too lazy to write proper answer, but first thought is: `if (condition) { do something while (condition) somethingElse }`.

Comment: @Austin "_*note: Do not confuse this with a do-while loop which runs at least once no matter what. I want a line of code that runs only if the while loop is run at least once._"

Comment: A note about efficiency: There are a lot of different types. You have speed, memory use, coding time, debugging time, maintaining time, and probably a few more. A lot of them conflict, so you need to pick and choose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
if ( condition )
{
    while(condition) {
       doSomething();
    }
    doSomethingElse(); 
}
```

Or

```
if ( bool b = condition )
{
    while( b) {
       doSomething();
       b = condition;
    }
    doSomethingElse(); 
}
```

or

```
if ( condition )
{
    do {
       doSomething();
    } while ( condition );
    doSomethingElse(); 
}
```

Comment: The `do..while` solution is the best choice, as it does not need to evaluate the `condition` twice on the 1st iteration, like the other presented solutions are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=0;
while(condition) {
    doSomething();
    count=count+1;
}if(count >=1) {
    // Enter the block of code that you want to run at least once }
```